# What is this orange button below the steering on a Mazda?

Tags: audio, mazda, part-identification

I checked the manual but did not see it. It seems to be an addition made by the previous buyer.

I also asked my mechanic but he does not know what it is.

[image: Orange Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a LOT like the attached photo, which is purportedly a switch which allows you to turn on a TV while driving. This would be part of an aftermarket AV system or an add-on for your current system (not quite sure).

[image]

[image]

Images and information obtained from [this site](https://www.goo-net.com/pit/shop/0128860/blog/229032).

**EDIT:** Here's [another site](https://www.datasystem-shopping.com/shopdetail/000000000046/) which may also be of some use, though it is in Japanese. If the button is what it seems to be, this would be the site of the company selling it.

Comment: Wow.  How did you find that?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - I put the image of the button into Google Images and let it do the work. The above pic I posted of the button was the only one which came up. So tracked it from there.

Comment: Thank you Paulster2. Great find there. It seems it is installed on older car models without Android Auto or Apple CarPlay to help with navigation and other modern  car capabilities.